# Match and replace hash comments

Tags: javascript, regex

##### What I'm looking for

I would like to match *hash comments* excluding *inline comments* in PowerShell . I can match them using `#(?<!<#)(?![<>])(.*)$` (see [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nFvbj5/3)). However I would want to achieve this by not using lookbehind. Is there any way I can get the same (or closest) behavior to the regex with lookbehind?

A regex only solution would be nice but I would also appreciate solutions JavaScript only solutions.

##### What I tried

My best was try `#(?!.*>)(.*)$` (see [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pIMXiz/1)), but I'm unhappy that it misses anything that has`>` after `#`.

I also tried writing JavaScript only parsing but it got very complex (more than 30 lines, see [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/QW9XPNfb)) and was very slow.

##### Why I need it

I use this to inline PowerShell used in an open-source project ([GitHub code](https://github.com/undergroundwires/privacy.sexy/blob/0.11.0/src/application/Parser/Script/Compiler/Expressions/Pipes/PipeDefinitions/InlinePowerShell.ts#L29-L35)). However, the project is online and runs on browser ([website](https://privacy.sexy)) and unfortunately I realized that it does not work in Safari as Safari does not  yet support lookbehind ([caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind)).

##### Syntax: Hash comment vs inline comment

Rule: Match all hash comments but exclude inline comments

*Hash comments* in PowerShell, just like in bash and other languages starts from hash (`#`) and continues until the end of the line.

```
Write-Host "Hello world" # Here is a hash comment
```

*Inline comments* in PowerShell is between `<#` and `#>`

```
Write-Host <# Here is an inline comment #> "Hello world"
```

Comment: I think regex has the ^ line start character,  you can split your string by carriage returns\line breaks and check with `^[#]

Comment: Safari has become a non-modern browser in so many aspects, not unlike IE <=11

Comment: @ISAE thanks, I think for own parsing logic splitting into new lines is good. But `^[#]`gives me only the ones that starts with # not the ohers. @WiktorStribiżew This is perfect for matching ALL comments but I'd like to exclude inline comments (first part `<#.*?#>`) @Dexygen you are right, shame for Apple..

Comment: You are thinking about it wrong. You do not need to "exclude" anything. You can match but not capture, or capture, and then apply any logic you want. So, please, explain what you want to achieve, what do you need to match all these comments for? Remove? Replace? Extract? Provide a test case to make it 100% clear.

Answer (score 3):

With regular expressions, that represent plain text patterns, you can not just match pieces of texts, you can also *capture* parts of the matches. Once you capture a substring, you can apply any logic you want after that, be it replacing or keeping parts of the string.

To replace the comments, you can use

```js
text = text.replace(/(<#.*?#>)|#.*/g, (m, g) => g ? g : "REPLACED")
```

To remove the comments, you can use

```js
text = text.replace(/(<#.*?#>)|#.*/g, "$1")
```

In both cases, the pattern is `(<#.*?#>)|#.*`:

- `(<#.*?#>)` - Group 1: a `<#` text, then any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, and then `#>` text
- `|` - or
- `#.*` - `#` char and the rest of the line.

In the first case, `(m, g) => g ? g : "REPLACED"` replacement keeps `g`roup 1 value if Group 1 matched (`m` stands for the whole match and `g` stands for the Group 1 value). In the second case, the Group 1 value is put back if it was matched with the help of the `$1` backreference. It represents an empty string if Group 1 did not match.

Answer (score 2):

You could match the following regular expression.

```
^(?:<#.*?#>|[^#])*(#.*)?
```

The capture group, if not empty, contains the comment to be removed.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Aj6IeI/1)

Hover the cursor over each element of the expression at the link to obtain a description of its function.